# Python print " character

Tags: python, string

How can I print the `"` character?

I know that printing the % symbol is `print "%%"` but I do not know how to print the `"` character.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what search terms did you try on Google? The above link was the first result I got for "python quotation mark".

Comment: You have to excuse my lack of English. I tried to search just typing the " symbol and nothing could came out. So silly...

Comment: No problem - punctuation marks are notoriously difficult to search for if you don't know their name.

Comment: Symbolhound.com lets you search for symbols as well as words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just escape it:

```
print("\"")
```

Or as zondo mentioned:

```
print('"')
```

Even:

```
print("""""""")
```

(Triple double-quoted string with `"` inside)

```
print('''"''')
```

(Triple single-quoted string with `"` inside)

Output:

```
"
```

See [this page](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Comment: or what about `print("""he said "heya" to her""")`?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways.  Either escape the character with a backslash or use a different kind of quotation marks:

```
print("\"")
```

or

```
print('"')
```